# Ubuntu says no LTS release available, trying to go 18.04 to 20.04.1

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade to the newest LTS. What am I missing here?

```
chris@chris-x1 ~> lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

chris@chris-x1 ~> sudo do-release-upgrade

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

**Update with resolution**

1. Run `software-properties-gtk`
2. In the Ubuntu Software tab I selected the first 4 checkboxes (probably too many). This updates a bunch of caches
3. Ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`

At this point the installation was kinda wonky. I had missing icons and my theme customizations were MIA. Couldn't run upgrades due to broken packages so I ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and this seemed to resolve everything. I can sort out the rest later.

Comment: Be patient. It will come.

Comment: Do you have your software updates set to notify for new LTS release?

Comment: In the duplicate I mention *days*, and my general rule of thumb is the Tuesday following the release Thursday (as earliest for all releases inc. non-LTS, and we're here now), however this was a LTS and the cycle included python2 EOL, Qt4 EOL... so to ensure *stability* to existing LTS users, the *taps* are turned only when it's considered the fewest people possible will have issues, ie. ensuring *stability*.

Comment: Alternatively, You can boot of a Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS ISO! Click Install! You should get options. Select Upgrade from [release] to [release]! Most things will be kept and you will be in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Still not allowing me to. If the option is not there by the end of the week I'll do what Jayden W. suggested.

Comment: upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 is disabeled at the moment,there is a couple of bugs that needs to be solved first.one of the bugs might leave your computer in an unbootable state after the upgrade,so please be patient for a few more days and try again later.(i did read about this a few days back here on ask).

Comment: read my update, too late